# How can I create a postgresql database during the installation of my project?

Tags: c#, postgresql, setup-project

I create a setup project in C# for my windows service. I wanted to know how can I create a postgresql database during the installation of my project.

Comment: is this for development purposes or for deployment? Also, have you tried anything yet, if you have please let us have a look at the attempt and maybe we can help a little better

Comment: @MarkDavies It's for deployment and I don't try something because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You probably need to read into software packaging, and I mean really study it because this sort of stuff is complex. For now I think this quesiton doesn't really have much to do with programming so I'm going to flag it for a moderator to review

Answer (score -1):

Instead of installing a postres instance you could use the postgres binaries (https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries) and deploy them in your setup as a self-contained module.

Comment: Ok so postgres binaries will allow me to create the database of my project ?

Comment: Yes. You can start the postgres database from your application as a child process and can operate on it like on any other postgres instance. That's how we do it in our project.

Comment: When I double click on initdb.exe nothing append so how can I execute it on my project ?

Comment: For this you should study the documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/) and also think about using an ORM, e.g. EF (https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/).